# Circle of Scattering for Normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> A random point $(X,Y)$ has a normal distribution on a plane with circular scattering with
>
> $$ E(X)=E(Y)=0 \quad \text{and} \quad \operatorname{var}(X)=\operatorname{var}(Y)=\sigma^2. $$
>
> The distance of the point $(X,Y)$ from the centre of scattering  is $R$. Find $E(R)$.

I found the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ and then found out the distribution of $R$ using a simple polar transformation. I am getting that

$$E(R)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sigma.$$

But, I think this is not correct and I am failing to convince myself regarding the independence assumption of $X,Y$.

Help!

Comment: Your intuition is that it is not correct, why would it not be correct?

Comment: Hint: $R/\sigma\sim\chi_2$.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Especially, why do you even need to consider independence when you can directly compute the distribution of $R$ out of the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$? Also I can assure you that your result is correct.

Comment: For context, perhaps look at 'Rayleigh distribution' and 'Box-Muller transformation'. If $\sigma = 1$ then squared dist to random point is CHISQ(df=2).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simulation following my Comment. Using R, we sample a sample a million values $X$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ and, independently, a million values $Y.$

```
set.seed(822);  m = 10^6
x = rnorm(m);  y = rnorm(m)
r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
mean(r);  sqrt(pi/2)
[1] 1.252897          # aprx E(R) = 1.2533
[1] 1.253314          # exact

# 50,000 points for plotting
n = 50000;  X = x[1:n];  Y = y[1:n];  R = r[1:n]
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 plot(X, Y, pch=".")
 hist(R, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="Simulated Rayleigh Dist'n")
  curve(x*exp(-.5*x^2), 0, 5, add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
 plot(ecdf(R))
  curve(1-exp(-.5*x^2), 0, 5, add=T, col="red", lwd=3, lty="dashed")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

The figure below shows 50,000 bivariate normal points, a histogram of
the simulated Rayleigh distribution $(\sigma=1)$ with the exact PDF (red), and an empirical
CDF plot of the simulated Rayleigh distribution along with the exact CDF (dashed red).
Details of the Rayleigh distribution are shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution#Related_distributions).
As you say, the derivation of the PDF involves changing to polar coordinates.

[image]